# Why is it when I make set the display of a DIV to flex the background color and z-indexing act buggy

Tags: html, css, vue.js, tailwind-css

Im using Vue with Tailwind and this is my template.

```html
<template>
  <div id="navbar" class="absolute h-16 w-full bottom-0 z-50 flex justify-between items-center">
    <div class="">
      <img src="/images/home/logo.png" class="h-16 ml-2">
    </div>
    <div class="w-2/5 h-full flex justify-around items-center">
      <button class="bg-white relative my-0 h-9 px-6 rounded-2xl hover:bg-purple-700 hover:text-white transition-all duration-300" @click="sunrise()">Say Hello</button>
      <button class="bg-white relative my-0 h-9 px-6 rounded-2xl hover:bg-purple-700 hover:text-white transition-all duration-300">About Me</button>
      <button class="bg-white relative my-0 h-9 px-6 rounded-2xl hover:bg-purple-700 hover:text-white transition-all duration-300">My Work</button>
      <button class="bg-white relative my-0 h-9 px-6 rounded-2xl hover:bg-purple-700 hover:text-white transition-all duration-300">Resume</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <section class="relative w-full h-screen before:content-[''] before:absolute before:bottom-0 before:w-full before:h-[400px] before:bg-gradient-to-t before:from-black before:to-transparent before:z-40">
    <img src="/images/home/stars.png" id="stars" class="absolute top-0 left-0 w-full h-full object-cover pointer-events-none">
    <img src="/images/home/moon.png" id="moon" class="absolute top-0 left-0 w-full h-full object-cover pointer-events-none translate-x-20 ">
    <img src="/images/home/sun.png" id="sun" class="absolute top-0 left-0 w-full h-full object-cover pointer-events-none translate-x-20 hidden ">
    <img src="/images/home/hills.png" id="hills" class="absolute top-0 left-0 w-full h-full object-cover pointer-events-none ">
    <img src="/images/home/trees.png" id="trees" class="absolute top-0 left-0 w-full h-full object-cover pointer-events-none">
  </section>
  <div id="problem-div" class="flex">
    <div class="text-white relative bg-black flex flex-col items-center justify-center">
      <h2 class="text-3xl font-bold mb-10 mt-20">
        Hi, I'm Justin.
      </h2>
      <p class="text-lg max-w-[70ch] text-center leading-8">
        Venture billions upon billions encyclopaedia galactica a still more glorious dawn awaits extraplanetary are creatures of the cosmos. Concept of the number one Hypatia courage of our questions made in the interiors of collapsing stars the ash of stellar alchemy not a sunrise but a galaxyrise. Kindling the energy hidden in matter the only home we've ever known descended from astronomers vanquish the impossible dream of the mind's eye realm of the galaxies.
        Preserve and cherish that pale blue dot radio telescope something incredible is waiting to be known rings of Uranus a very small stage in a vast cosmic arena hundreds of thousands.<br><br> A mote of dust suspended in a sunbeam star stuff harvesting star light great turbulent clouds tingling of the spine not a sunrise but a galaxyrise citizens of distant epochs. Extraordinary claims require extraordinary evidence paroxysm of global death concept of the number one a mote of dust suspended in a sunbeam globular star cluster with pretty stories for which there's little good evidence.
        Extraordinary claims require extraordinary evidence take root and flourish Hypatia stirred by starlight encyclopaedia galactica radio telescope. <br><br>Two ghostly white figures in coveralls and helmets are softly dancing Sea of Tranquility invent the universe rings of Uranus gathered by gravity emerged into consciousness. Something incredible is waiting to be known star stuff harvesting star light courage of our questions intelligent beings rich in mystery hundreds of thousands. Network of wormholes a mote of dust suspended in a sunbeam from which we spring citizens of distant epochs with pretty stories for which there's little good evidence courage of our questions.
        Culture star stuff harvesting star light finite but unbounded trillion Flatland paroxysm of global death? Take root and flourish permanence of the stars kindling the energy hidden in matter astonishment across the centuries the ash of stellar alchemy? Made in the interiors of collapsing stars rich in heavy atoms made in the interiors of collapsing stars concept of the number one made in the interiors of collapsing stars great turbulent clouds.
        Corpus callosum brain is the seed of intelligence shores of the cosmic ocean a very small stage in a vast cosmic arena intelligent beings extraplanetary. <br><br>Kindling the energy hidden in matter hundreds of thousands Hypatia another world Cambrian explosion kindling the energy hidden in matter? Bits of moving fluff courage of our questions bits of moving fluff courage of our questions courage of our questions from which we spring.
        Realm of the galaxies colonies a still more glorious dawn awaits vanquish the impossible cosmos cosmic fugue? Shores of the cosmic ocean bits of moving fluff invent the universe Apollonius of Perga from which we spring something incredible is waiting to be known. Bits of moving fluff the sky calls to us the only home we've ever known from which we spring bits of moving fluff as a patch of light.
        Tendrils of gossamer clouds laws of physics two ghostly white figures in coveralls and helmets are softly dancing emerged into consciousness Hypatia cosmos. Great turbulent clouds two ghostly white figures in coveralls and helmets are softly dancing another world finite but unbounded with pretty stories for which there's little good evidence as a patch of light. Sea of Tranquility star stuff harvesting star light made in the interiors of collapsing stars bits of moving fluff a still more glorious dawn awaits extraordinary claims require extraordinary evidence and billions upon billions upon billions upon billions upon.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-black">
      <img src="/images/home/me.png" class="h-[300px]">
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

and this is how it functions now.

[image]

but if I set the div #problem-div to flex it does this. I have absolutely no idea why!

[image]

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: You may  be running into a stacking context problem when you introduce the flex. See for example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context